# how to add new page (page break) to article

Tags: tikz-pgf, page-breaking, article

This is my code, I am learning how to use the TikZ package and am trying to put different examples on different pages.  I would like to have a page break between lines 22 & 24 if at all possible.  Thanks.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

  \usepackage{tikz}

  %optional libraries
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations,arrows}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \draw(1,0) -- (0,1) -- (-1,0) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;

  \draw[step=0.25cm, color=gray]
(-1,-1) grid (1,1);
  \draw[fill,color=blue!30,draw=red, line width=2pt, opacity=0.5]   
(1,0) -- (0,1) -- (-1,0) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;

  \draw (0,0) grid (10,10);
  \draw (5,5) circle (5);
  \draw (0,10) rectangle (-2,8);
  \draw (5,5) circle (3 and 5);
  \draw (10,0) arc (-90:90:5);

 %Define the desired points
 \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
 \coordinate (A) at (360.0/7.0 *0 : 1);
 \coordinate (B) at (360.0/7.0 *1 : 1);
 \coordinate (C) at (360.0/7.0 *2 : 1);
 \coordinate (D) at (360.0/7.0 *3 : 1);
 \coordinate (E) at (360.0/7.0 *4 : 1);
 \coordinate (F) at (360.0/7.0 *5 : 1);
 \coordinate (G) at (360.0/7.0 *6 : 1);

%Draw the edges
\draw(A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (E) -- (F) -- (G) -- cycle;

%Add spokes
\draw (origin) -- (A) (origin) -- (B) (origin) -- (C) (origin) -- (D) 
 (origin) -- (E)    (origin) -- (F) (origin) -- (G);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can finish a TikZ picture and start another one. For example by putting this in between `\end{tikzpicture}\newpage\begin{tikzpicture}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insert

```
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

is this your expected result?